# USA States Schools data base

Tags: data-request, education

Seeking an open database of schools across the states in the USA. Ideally, this database includes the schools name, address, **email address** and telephone number.

Seeking this dataset because we are a SaaS "Software as a Service" based company located in South Africa and want to market an app we developed to the the US States' education systems.

Comment: It sort of looks like you're asking us to help you spam. Having said that, do you mean high/middle/elementary schools, universities or what? The .EDU WHOIS records might be of considerable help.